# How can I get my text to not print one character per line?

Tags: java, text, output

I have this code which pulls the source code from the website listed. When the text is printed out each letter is in a different line. I need the line setup to be the same as the source code on chrome. How could I get it to print out like that?

```
package downloader;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Scannerup {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {

        URL obj = new URL("https://www.papajohns.com/");

        URLConnection con = obj.openConnection();

        InputStream in1 = con.getInputStream();

        int i;

        do {

            i = in1.read();

            if(i!=-1)
            {
                System.out.println((char)i);

            }
        }
        while(i!=-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: System.out.println((char)i); here you print a line for a char. change println (printLine) to print

Comment: `System.out.print((char)i)`

Comment: Andy, it's highly appreciated at SO, that you'd know the name of the language you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this

```
        if(i!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println((char)i);   ----------> You are using println
        }
```

Change it to

```
        if(i!=-1)
        {
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }
```

---

print() - will print the required output on the same line again and again. (This is what you should of used)

---

println() -  will print the output in the next line(This is what you use in your code)

Comment: ehm, no: println is what he used in his code. print is what he should have used. When providing an answer, please provide more information compared to what's only in the comments, and provide the correct answer

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it my friend. Wasn't focused 100%.